# How to populate a div with text of a class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="head-mono">
    <span class="mono_link"></span>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
   <div class="section_mono">
       <h2><a class="link_s">text</a></h2>
       <p>paragraph</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
   <div class="section_mono">
       <h2><a class="link_s">text</a></h2>
       <p>paragraph</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
   <div class="section_mono">
       <h2><a class="link_s">text</a></h2>
       <p>paragraph</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to populate the `class="mono_link"` with all the text of `link_s` (and then jump to the section on click).
I'm stuck on the first part, populating with the text, I tried with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mono_link").html(".section_mono".find('.link_s').text());
});
```

But it doesn't work. I'm fairly new to jQuery

Comment: Missing `$()` here `$(".section_mono")`

Comment: You're right! What a stupid mistake. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the selector `$(".section_mono")` missing parentheses.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mono_link").html($(".section_mono").find('.link_s').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head-mono">
  <span class="mono_link"></span>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="section_mono">
    <h2><a class="link_s">text</a></h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="section_mono">
    <h2><a class="link_s">text</a></h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="section_mono">
    <h2><a class="link_s">text</a></h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's this? You didn't explain anything and just dumped code. And if you're trying to point out the typo that was already pointed out in the comments you should just be voting to close the question as off-topic due to a typo

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what's a better way to answer. However I didn't see the comment. And I didn't even know that you can cote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo. Also in my opinion, there is no need to downvote just because you didn't like how it was presented. We are just trying to help, being rewarded with a downvote isn't really the community spirit.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing $ sign

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mono_link").html($(".section_mono").find('.link_s').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head-mono">
  <span class="mono_link"></span>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="section_mono">
    <h2><a class="link_s">text</a></h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="section_mono">
    <h2><a class="link_s">text</a></h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="section_mono">
    <h2><a class="link_s">text</a></h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As was noted in a comment. No need for an answer. In fact, you should just be voting to close the question as off-topic due to a typo